# Flutter webview plugin onUrlChanged is not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

I am trying to use the web view plugin in the flutter with the following code. However, I am only receiving the first 2 debug messages to the console. Does anyone know why this is? Could someone be able to point me in the direction of the answer? I found out about putting the listener to initState but that didn't work either.

Any solutions?
Here is my code for the widget.
(Installing on android btw)

```
Widget webView() {
    // OPEN WEBVIEW ACCORDING TO URL GIVEN
    print("debug");
    flutterWebviewPlugin.launch(instagram.url);
    // LISTEN CHANGES
    print("debug1");
    flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) async {
      print("debug2");
      // IF SUCCESS LOGIN
      if (url.contains(instagram.redirectUri)) {
        instagram.getAuthorizationCode(url);
        instagram.getTokenAndUserID().then((isDone) {
          if (isDone) {
            instagram.getLongLivedToken().then((isDone) {
              if(isDone){
                prefs.setString('token', instagram.longLivedAccessToken);
                instagram.getUserProfile().then((isDone){
                  if(isDone){
                    instagram.getAllMedias();
                    setState(() {
                      images = instagram.imageUrls;
                    });
                  }
                });
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
      print("Login successful");
      // NOW WE CAN CLOSE THE WEBVIEW
      flutterWebviewPlugin.close();
      Navigator.pop(context);

    });

    return WebviewScaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      url: instagram.url,
    );

  }
```

Comment: Why are you launching another webview when you already created a `WebviewScaffold`. That widget already launches the `url` property. Any reason why thine line, `flutterWebviewPlugin.launch(instagram.url);`, is added?

Comment: Because I thought it was necessary. I referenced this article: https://medium.com/@florian.gustin.business/how-to-use-flutter-api-instagram-basic-display-select-medias-from-instagram-profile-f5ce3e371ece

Comment: If you remove that line, does it still work? Also, how does the function `webView()` called? I think you also need to cancel your subscription of that stream.

Comment: It worked when I removed that line